# Error trying to install Charles Proxy 4.5.1 - "The bundled java installation is broken. Please uninstall and reinstall Charles"

Tags: java, config, charles-proxy

I had problems when i try install Charles Proxy 4.5.1.

has displayed the following error:

**"The bundled java installation is broken. Please uninstall and reinstall Charles"**

I already uninstalled and installed Charles, uninstalled and installed Java and Java SE Kit and the bug persists

Answer (score 16):

When I tried to use Charles 4.5.6 on Windows 10, I had a similar problem. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kQmI.png)

> ERROR: Could not load library: C:\Program Files\Charles\jdk\bin\server\jvm.dll
>   The bundled Java installation is broken. Please uninstall and reinstall Charles.

I don't know exactly what was wrong. But, it seems Charles couldn't load the dll file.

I installed "visual c++ runtime" and it was fixed.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

---

Installation of java 11 also worked in my case. But, I think java version is not the main problem here. Because Charles 4.5.x uses bundled jvm.

Comment: Thanks much for this - worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with java 8.231 and Charles 4.5.4, I solved by installing a previous version of Charles: v3.12.3

Regards

Comment: I did that too but would like to use the newer versions =/

Comment: However, Charles 32bit or 64 bit compatibility must also be tried